# Как замерить время выполнения кода в миллисекундах?

Tags: c++, время

Привет.

Использую функцию GetTickCount() для измерения времени выполнения в миллисекундах, но вот кусок кода:

```
UINT32 start = GetTickCount();
upper = lower + step;
while (upper < n) {
    result += (double)(upper-lower)/6.0*(func(lower,degree) + 4*func(double(upper+lower)/2,degree) + func(upper,degree));
    upper += step;
    lower += step;
}
if (upper >= n) {
    upper = n;
    result += (double)(upper-lower)/6.0*(func(lower,degree) + 4*func(double(upper+lower)/2,degree) + func(upper,degree));
}
UINT32 end = GetTickCount();
UINT32 diff = end - start;
```

В конце концов получается, что diff = 0. Если в while добавить какой-нибудь вывод (cout), то время наконец-таки замеряется. Так вот вопрос: как можно замерить время выполнения в миллисекундах? Уж больно быстро выполняется программа.

Comment: А если она у тебя выполняется быстрее одной миллисекунды и выдает правильный результат? P.S. cast в double не обязателен, если делить на константу типа double: (2.0; 4.2; 5.312).

Comment: Спасибо. Исправлю.
Мне просто нужно замерить время выполнения как-нибудь. Все перепробовал.

Comment: BOOL QueryPerformanceCounter(LARGE_INTEGER *lpPerformanceCount); возвращает количество системных "тиков".  
Попробуйте посчитать их, если миллисекунды - слишком большой масштаб.

Comment: @Garden Chamber, PCFreq = double(li.QuadPart)/1000.0; это в миллисекундах?

Comment: @js_cbs, не совсем понятно, что такое li.QuadPart. Для процессора с тактовой частотой 2Ghz, при условии, что PCFreq- Тактовая частота, li.quadPart=2M(hz) или 2000000(hz). Если вы хотите посчитать количество миллисекунд с помощью QueryPerformanceCounter(), то QueryPerformanceCounter/(тактовая частота)~= времени в секундах. Если умножить на тысячу, можно получить число ~= времени в милисекундах.

Comment: Дельту между QueryPerformanceCounter делят на QueryPerformanceFrequency и получают секунды.

Comment: Почему бы Вам не обернуть проверяемый код в цикл, который бы выполнялся 1000 раз? Получите в результате 7 милисекунд, будете знать, что Ваш код выполняется ~ 7/1000 милисекунды.

Comment: @smallFish, компилятор подумает, а зачем нам столько раз считать одно и то же, и выкинет все циклы. В случае простого повторения нужно быть осторожней и проверять, что намеряли то, что хотели.

Comment: @IronVbif, наверное Вы правы, а сделать ключевые переменные volatile не поможет?

Comment: @smallFish, тогда можно намерять дорогие volatile write вместо вычислений. volatile поможет, если будет одна запись на итерацию такого цикла, например, переприсваивание результата по завершению в volatile переменную. Надежней сохранить просто все результаты вычислений, а потом вывести в файл или консоль (уже вне измерения времени).

Comment: Спасибо всем.

Comment: Ответ получен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы никогда не сможете замерить точное время выполнения вашего кода. Многозадачность в Windows - интересная штука, в любой момент времени операционная система может решить переключить контекст выполнения с вашей на другую задачу... И в итоге вы получите не совсем те результаты :) И присуще это не только Windows. В подобных ситуациях обычно поступают следующим образом: замеряют выполнение N повторений требуемого участка, и затем вычисляют среднее время выполнения одного повторения...

Answer (score 1):

Если есть возможность использовать С++11, то подойдет:

```
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
...

for(int i = 0; a < 10; i++) { //Для получения среднего времени

    spaceholder_code(i); //Функция, выполняющая случайный код, дабы состояние перед выполнением тестируемого участка было разным.
    auto begin = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    my_finction(); //оцениваемый код.

    auto end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout<<chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(end-begin).count()<<"ns"<< endl;
}
```

В NetBeans для этого нужно добавить Project-> compiler-> additional options -> `-std=c++11`
Опцию можно включить и в других IDE.